# How do I make this html two columns of equal width with a margin in between?

Tags: html, css

I have some HTML that I cannot change, but I can change the CSS as much as I want. I need to make these:

1. two columns of equal width
2. A margin in between of `2em`
3. They have to take all the remaining width (parent width - 2em)
4. The boxes need to have a padding inside

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <a href="/page1" class="box">
        <img class="pic" src="/images/image1.png">
        <div class="description">the description</div>
    </a>
    <a href="/page2" class="box">
        <img class="pic" src="/images/image2.png">
        <div class="description">the description</div>
    </a>
</div>
```

I'm able to do it without any spacing between them with: `box-sizing: border-box;` but if I add in a margin-right, they no longer fit.

Comment: @AlexChar There's a well-known CSS property known as `display`, you can set it to `display: block;`

Comment: @AlexChar in html4 you'd be correct.   in html5, it is valid.  http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element  " states that the <a> element "may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables, and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive content within (e.g. buttons or other links)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it:

```
.parent .box
{
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0em;
    padding: 1em;
    float: left;
    font-size: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 0;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent .box:nth-child(odd)
{
    border-right: solid 1em #ffffff;
}

.parent .box:nth-child(even)
{
    border-left: solid 1em #ffffff;
}
```

The n-th child lets me add the spacing between them

Comment: careful, nth child is not supported in IE8 at least.

Comment: @MatthewA.McFarland This is mobile only.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try : It makes use of the `Calc()` function in css.

*Note: The border throws off the calculation a bit, so you will have to adjust the calc slightly. I just did it to show you how the boxes were laid out.*

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.box {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: calc(50% - 1.25em);
    display: inline-block;
}

.box:first-child {
    margin-right: 2em;
}
```

***[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fcvn6pbL/)***